# Resizing a dynamically allocated array passed by reference

Tags: c++

I am stuck in this problem: how to resize, inside a function, a dynamically allocated array, which has been passed, to the function, by reference.
I tried this, along with countless variations on this very approach. Of course this is just an example, it should print "john" ten times, expanding an array passed by reference that originally had only size 1 ( ie only 1 name ).

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int NumLast=-1;


int Surname(string *MyData)
{

          for (int i=0; i<10 ; i++)
          {
            NumLast++;
            string *Temp = new string[NumLast+1];   // temporary array 
            for (int jjj=0; jjj<NumLast; jjj++)
                Temp[jjj]=MyData[jjj];
            delete[] MyData;
            MyData=Temp;
            MyData[NumLast]="John";
          }
          return 0;
}


void main()
{ 
     string *Data = new string[1]; // inizializza l'array 
     Surname(&*Data);
     for (int iii=0; iii<10; iii++)
              cout << Data[iii] << endl; 

     system("pause");
}
```

Comment: `void main` is non-standard. Use `int main()`. Seeing as how you can use `std::string`, is `std::vector` or similar allowed as well?

Comment: why not use `std::vector`?

Comment: By the way, your function is accessing the new array out of bounds. `NumLast` starts as -1, gets incremented to 0, the array is made with size 1, then `MyDara[1]` is assigned to.

Comment: This code (all 15 lines of it) has so many bugs, it's not even funny. Seriously.

Comment: And with a vector, this simply becomes `std::vector<std::string> Data(1); Data.resize(newSize, "John");` Not to mention it has a `size()` function and iterators.

Comment: BTW void main() is one of standard variants. In this case it is equivalent to main() returning 0 (at least AFAIR for previous ANSI C and C++ 2003).

Comment: @RomanNikitchenko, I'm pretty sure C++03 didn't allow it, either. I know for sure C++11 does not. I don't know if it started with C99 or what, but C currently accepts implementation-defined signatures.

Comment: @chris You are right. Just reviewed chain of standards - there is one misleading point in 'program termination' chapter but starting from original ANSI C standard they state main() SHALL be defined with return value of type int.

Comment: My apologies for my errors ( I am still learning C++ ), my sincere thanks for all this help, my promise that I will study everything carefully. I love to learn: I will forever be a perpetual student ! :-)

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass by reference. You are passing by value. You are getting

```
&*Data                                              = Data
The value of the address of what is pointed to Data = Data
```

Then you pass it by value to Surname. Anything `Surname` does to it won't affect `Data` in `main`.

```
int Surname(string *MyData)  // This will take a copy of whatever you passed in to MyData
```

should be (The reference operator should be on the function definition.)

```
int Surname(string*& MyData)
                  ^^
```

And the call will be

```
void main()
{ 
     string *Data = new string[1];
     Surname(Data);  // The function will take a reference of data.
```

Buy may I ask why you are allocating in a loop?

Comment: I am allocating in a loop because the Data array should be filled by file paths inserted in that array while the function extracts the file names included in a directory.

Answer (score 0):

1. Looks like std::vector is best solution for your case.
2. If you really need to reallocate manually, think about old school malloc(), free(), realloc() interface. Main thing to remember is to not intermix it with C++ new/delete interface despite usually new / delete is implemented using malloc() / free().
3. If you need array you should pass not array but pointer (or reference) to array (double pointer). In case of std::vector it is enough to pass reference to it.
4. Yet another argument to use reference to std::vector - in case of pointer to array caller should be notified somehow what is new array size.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to try and go through your code line by line and point out some of the issues and highlight what's going on. I will start from your `main` function:

```
void main()
{ 
    string *Data = new string[1]; // inizializza l'array 
    Surname(&*Data);

    for (int iii=0; iii<10; iii++)
        cout << Data[iii] << endl;
}
```

OK, so what this code does is allocate one string and save the pointer to it in a variable called `Data`.

Then it *dereferences* `Data`, thus, getting back a `string` and then gets the *address of* of that string (i.e. gets back the same thing as `Data`).

In other words this code:

```
    Surname(&*Data);
```

does exactly the same as this code:

```
    Surname(Data);
```

So, now let's take a look at `Surname`:

```
int Surname(string *MyData)
{
    for (int i=0; i<10 ; i++)
    {
        NumLast++;
        string *Temp = new string[NumLast+1];   // temporary array 
        for (int jjj=0; jjj<NumLast; jjj++)
            Temp[jjj]=MyData[jjj];
        delete[] MyData;
        MyData=Temp;
        MyData[NumLast]="John";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This weird function accepts a pointer to a string and loops 10 times doing stuff. Let's see what happens in the first iteration of the loop...

First, it increments `NumLast` (which goes from `-1` to `0`). Then it allocate an array of strings, of length `NumLast + 1` (i.e. of length `1`). So far so good.

Now you might think the function would enter the `for` loop. But it won't: remember that at that point `NumLast` and `jjj` are both `0` and therefore, `jjj < NumLast` is false.

The code will then `delete[] MyData` (that is, it will delete whatever `MyData` points to), set `MyData` to point to the temporary array allocated earlier in the loop, and then set the first element (at index `0`) to the string `"John"`.

In the second iteration of the loop, the function again increments `NumLast` (which will now be 1). It will again allocate an array of strings, this time of length `2`.

The loop will be entered this time. It will copy the first entry from `MyData` into the first entry from `Temp`. And it will exit.

Again, `MyData` will be deleted, and the pointer will be made to point to the newly allocated array.

Rinse. Lather. Repeat.

Finally, the function will exit. We go back to main, which will now execute this bit of code:

```
for (int iii=0; iii<10; iii++)
    cout << Data[iii] << endl;
```

Wait a second though. Where does `Data` point to? Well... it points to data that has already been deleted long ago. Why?

Well, `Surname` received a *copy* of the `Data` pointer. When it called `delete[] MyData` it deleted the array that it `MyData` pointed to (which was the same array that `Data` pointed to). When `Surname` later did `MyData=Temp` all that changed was `MyData` (the copy of the pointer *local* to the function `Surname`) and `Data` (the pointer in `main`) was unaffected and continued to point to the now deleted memory.

Others have explained how you can get the effect you want and I won't repeat what they wrote. But I would urge you to sit down and think about what `Surname` does and how the code is unclear and confusing and how it can be rewritten so that it's easier to understand and less prone to error.

Comment: No need to apologize. We all made mistakes at some point. The important thing is, as you say, to learn.

Comment: THANKS TO EVERYBODY !  THE PROBLEM IS OFFICIALLY SOLVED !  :-)

Answer (score 0):

For those who in the future will need the solution to the same problem here is the amended code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int NumLast=-1;
int Surname(string *&MyData)
{       
     for (int i=0; i<10 ; i++)
     {
           NumLast++;
           string *Temp = new string[NumLast+1];   
           for (int jjj=0; jjj<NumLast; jjj++)
                Temp[jjj]=MyData[jjj];
           delete[] MyData;
           MyData=Temp;
           MyData[NumLast]="franci";
      }
      return 0;
}


void main()
{ 
      string *Data = new string[1]; // inizializza l'array 
      Surname(Data);  
      for (int iii=0; iii<10; iii++)
           cout << Data[iii] << endl;    
      system("pause");
}
```